# Cannot update Swift project on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I'm using Xcode, I have updated my Swift project's some properties like bundle name and application resolution from storyboard's property inspector.

But when I debug the project, I cannot see the new values,
although I have cleaned and builded again from Product menu
and although I have removed the project and tried to debug on the phone again.

How can I fix this?

**Update**

I see the info.plist isn't saved. The bundle name now changed but still I cannot update the application resolution.

Comment: What do you mean by "storyboard's resolution" ?

Comment: I mean application resolution that is debugged and have ran on the phone.

Comment: I have updated, thanks.

Comment: @mrbengi Do you mean that you want the app run at retina resolution? Have you added a launch screen nib, or launch images?

Comment: I don't know what resolution it should be in. No I didn't have set a launch image. Firstly I have setted 4.7 inch and now I cannot change to 3.5 inch. I'm using a webview.